# Replace capture group of dynamic size

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to replace the first part of regex for a URL with asterisks. Depending on the regex, for example:

**Case 1**

`http://example.com/path1/path2?abcd` => `http://example.com/path1/**********`

**Regex 1**: `/^(https?:\/\/.+\/path1\/?)(.+)/`but I want each character in group 2 to be replaced individually with `*`

or

**Case 2**

`person@example.com` => `******@example.com`

**Regex 2**

`/^(.+)(@.+)$/`, similarly I want all characters in the *first* capture group to be replaced individually with `*`

I have tried to use capture groups, but then, I'm left with `*@example.com`

```js
let email = `person@example.com`;
let regex = /^(.+)(@.+)$/;
console.log(email.replace(regex, '*$2'));
```

```js
let url = `http://example.com/path1/path2?abcd`;
let regex = /^(https?:\/\/.+\/path1\/?)(.+)/;
console.log(url.replace(regex, '$1*'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the sticky flag y (but Internet Explorer doesn't support it):

```
s = s.replace(/(^https?:\/\/.*?\/path1\/?|(?!^))./gy, '$1*')
```

But the simplest (and that is supported everywhere), is to use a function as replacement parameter.

```
s = s.replace(/^(https?:\/\/.+\/path1\/?)(.*)/, function (_, m1, m2) {
    return m1 + '*'.repeat(m2.length);
});
```

---

For the second case, you can simply check if there's an `@` after the current position:

```
s = s.replace(/.(?=.*@)/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```js
let email = `person@example.com`;
let regex = /[^@]/gy;
console.log(email.replace(regex, '*'));

// OR
console.log(email.replace(/(.*)@/, function ($0,$1) { 
     return '*'.repeat($1.length) + "@";
}));
```

and

```js
let url = `http://example.com/path1/path2?abcd`;
let regex = /^(https?:\/\/.+\/path1\/?)(.*)/gy;
console.log(url.replace(regex, (_,$1,$2) => `${$1}${'*'.repeat($2.length)}` ));
// OR
console.log(url.replace(regex, function (_,$1,$2) { 
     return $1 + ('*'.repeat($2.length)); 
}));
```

In case of `.replace(/[^@]/gy, '*')`, each char other than `@` from the start of the string is replaced with `*` (so, up to the first `@`).

In case of `.replace(/(.*)@/, function ($0,$1) { return '*'.repeat($1.length) + "@"; })`, all chars up to the last `@` are captured into Group 1 and then the match is replaced with the same amount of asterisks as the length of the Group 1 value + the `@` char (it should be added into the replacement pattern as it is used as part of the consuming regex part).

The `` .replace(regex, (_,$1,$2) => `${$1}${'*'.repeat($2.length)}` ) `` follows the same logic as the case described above: you capture the part you need to replace, pass it into the anonymous callback method and manipulate its value using a bit of code.